# What is default unit of calculated area in turf.js?

Tags: javascript, turf

Here is a good example how to calculate area in turf.js 
http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_area.html

But what is its unit of area measurement (acre/hectare) ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like square meters based on your link. Unless that's not what you're looking for.

[image: turf.js area return]